# Dropwizard Custom log file via Logback

Tags: java, logging, logback, dropwizard

Looking at the source code for dropwizard I can see that there is custom glue code to read the .yml file and set up logging.

I want my own custom log file, but I'd like to use the rotation and compression that already exists in dropwizard.

Is there a way, short of cloning the code to do this?

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/logging

Specifically it looks like need to create my own class which inherits from io.dropwizard.FileAppenderFactory

Or am I attacking this problem from the wrong angle?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way but you need to change the dropwizard source and recompile it again if you are using the lib.In the Application class of dropwizard that you are extending there is static block like blow,just comment the lines and use your own logback.xml file.It really is a pain in the ....

```
static {
    // make sure spinning up Hibernate Validator doesn't yell at us
    LoggingFactory.bootstrap();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you just want to specify the file to which to log correct?

In that case in your configuration.yml file you just need to add a file logging configuration:

```
logging:

  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO,
  # DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: DEBUG

  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: ./path/to/logfile.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./path/to/logfile-%d.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 5
      timeZone: UTC
```

Replace the "/path/to/logfile" with the path you want the file log to be. Not that on rotation %d will be replaced by the date of the rotation, according to the [documentation](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#file-logging).

Also check the different [configuration options](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/configuration.html#file) for the file logger.

Comment: Note: dropwizard 0.6 doesn't support use of 'appenders' in the config file, but 0.7 does.

Comment: Can I use my existing logback.xml file along with yml file?